# How to achieve the following effect with libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I'm developping a game with libGDX. I have a question: Know the initial coordinates and target coordinates, as the picture shows, how to achieve the parabolic effect of the bullet ? to achieve the operation of shells . Who can teach me ? or tell me some tutorial. Tks

picture

[image]

Comment: You need Box2D to implement those.

Comment: To determine the initial velocity to hit a certain target, I think you need some basic college freshman level calculus.

Comment: That's not related with libgdx, this is basic physics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some physics to your app (ex. Box2d). Then you 'throw' canon ball with some velocity and some direction/angle. 
Physics engine do rest for you.
Here you have tutorial for box2d: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXovY2KTing

Very very basic example for throw something without box2d. For your example you need to calculate right 'power' for target position.

```
public class SampleApp extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    Sprite sprite;
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector2 terminateVelocity = new Vector2(2000, 2000);
    Vector2 friction = new Vector2(200, 300);
    Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector2 launchPower = new Vector2(0, 0);
    boolean shotNow;

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        // ...
        // here render your stuff
    }

    public void shot(float power)
    {
        // Calculate x launch power
        launchPower.x = ((power - sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()*0.5f) / 2f) + velocity.x;
        // We want to end our fly at ground
        launchPower.y = ((0 - sprite.getY()) / 2f) + velocity.y;
        // Setup start position
        position.x = sprite.getX();
        position.y = sprite.getY();
        // Add some acc to velocity
        velocity.add(launchPower);
        shotNow = true;
    }

    public void update(float dt)
    {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            shot(900);
        }
        // Very basic sprite movement.
        // For best results you should implement more physics (acceleration etc.)
        if (shotNow && position.y > 0) {
            // Friction/gravity
            velocity.x = MathUtils.clamp(velocity.x - friction.x * dt, -terminateVelocity.x, terminateVelocity.x);
            velocity.y = MathUtils.clamp(velocity.y - friction.y * dt, -terminateVelocity.y, terminateVelocity.y);
            position.add(velocity.x * dt, velocity.y * dt);
            sprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        }
    }
}
```